# PowerShell Script to Open and select Network Places?

Tags: powershell, vbscript, namespaces, showdialog

I have a VbScript that prompts the user to select a folder. The folder is typically on a network. For Vista and XP, the VbScript BrowseForFolder works fine.

However, for 7, 8, 8.1, and soon 10, the BrowseForFolder doesn't show the network :| So I detect the OS, and if it's 7 or later, I tried using powerShell, but it doesn't show the network list.

The namespace I'm trying to see, and set as the default start location is the Network place.

::{208d2c60-3aea-1069-a2d7-08002b30309d}

Saved as getFolder.ps1 in the temp folder is

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;
$Folder = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog;
$Folder.ShowNewFolderButton = $true;
$Folder.SelectedPath = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyComputer");
[void]$Folder.ShowDialog();
$Folder.SelectedPath;
```

Currently I'm working on Windows 10 TP build 9879, but I have similar behavior on Windows 8. In theory, this is to work out of box.

The calling VBScript is essentially

```
Dim oShell
If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists( "elevated" ) = False Then
 CreateObject( "Shell.Application" ).ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevated", "", "runas", 1
 WScript.Quit
Else
 Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
 oShell.CurrentDirectory = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" ).GetParentFolderName( WScript.ScriptFullName )
End If

Dim tmpFolder, psScrpt, psLine, execmd, pth
Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
tmpFolder = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%temp%" )
psScrpt = getFolder.ps1

psLine = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command " & tmpFolder & "\" & psScrpt

Set execmd = shl.Exec( psLine )
execmd.StdIn.Close

pth = Trim( Replace( execmd.StdOut.ReadAll, vbNewLine, "", 1, -1, vbTextCompare ) )
Wscript.Echo pth
```

The interesting thing is, when I Right-Click the PowerShell script, and select "*Run with PowerShell*" it shows me what I would like to see though I'm clearly not getting my nameSpace right, and one cannot type a location :\

When I run it from my vbScript I only see "My Computer": C drive, USB drives, Optical, Mapped Drives. However, the *running-from-inside-script* version allows me to type in a path, *\SomeServer\SomeShare*, and it is accepted. The "*Run With PowerShell*" doesn't show that.

So yeah, I'm confused and in need of help - any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems in your powershell script. First, the `$Folder` object doesn't have a `SelectedFolder` member (it's `SelectedPath`). To see members, type `$Folder | gm` on your command prompt. Second, you can access special folders using the `GetFolderPath` method available on `System.Environment`, providing the special folder name.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Folder = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$Folder.ShowNewFolderButton = $true
$Folder.SelectedPath = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath("NetworkShortcuts")
[void]$Folder.ShowDialog()
$Folder.SelectedPath
```

I can't test this script on Windows 10 but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: THANK YOU - That whole SelectedFolder doesn't exist is one of those things I was searching for :) I'm pretty new to PowerShell scripting :\

Comment: Grrr - I pressed enter and it submitted before I finished my comment.  <br> <br> Anyway, I don't get the error message, but it still does not show the Network  when called from within a VBScript... So i'm thinking it's a Window bug. <br> <br> I tried to +1 your response, but it wouldn't let me as I'm new. So in a few days, if no one else comments, I'll close this as a bug in Win10. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm an idiot - after further testing, it seems my OS test wasn't working correctly :\ It was defaulting to the VBScript getFolder :(